# how to pass multiple args into jq?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am trying to write a new json file. I want to define multiple variables then set them with piping to different properties in the new json file.

```
jq --arg dnb "$DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT" --arg origin "$DOMAIN_ID_BUILT" \ 
   '.Origins.Items[0].DomainName = $dnb' | '.Origins.Items[0].Id = $origin' distconfig.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" distconfig.json
```

This works with just one variable: --arg NAME VALUE pattern, but when I add in a second arg and use piping `jq ... 'x1 = y1 | x2 = y2, e.g.` it breaks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

pipe should be **inside the filter**. and, consider using assignment operator to shorten your code:

```
jq --arg dnb "$DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT" \
   --arg origin "$DOMAIN_ID_BUILT" \
   '.Origins.Items[0] |= ( .DomainName = $dnb | .Id = $origin )' \
distconfig.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" distconfig.json
```

Comment: Could the values of the keys (e.g. `DomainName` and `Id`) be passed as arguments and used in the same way?

Comment: @msoutopico Yeah. You'd do `.[$foo]` instead of `.DomainName` in that case.

Comment: @msoutopico love your comment above! Tell me, how can `.Origins.Items[0]` be passed as an argument?